# Strict Standards Off ~E_STRICT PHP 5.3

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a script that need Strict Standards Off  ~E_STRICT, but I cant understand how can I off strict standards on PHP. I have centos 6.4 with WHM installed VPS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repport *all* errors but stric, use `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);`. If you want to repport *all* errors, use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` if you want to log *all* errors but not show them, use `ini_set('display_errors', '0'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` or change the `display_errors` directive in the `php.ini` manually and set it to `off`.

Comment: But if you **don't** want to log _any_ error, just use `error_reporting(0)`